Loading Fuzzywuzzy into conda environment on VS Code won't work
I currently cannot install fuzzywuzzy but fuzzy matching is quite vital to a data project I'm working on as the dataset contains thousands of points and needs to be grouped computationally. I'm fairly new to VS Code so perhaps that is why but used the terminal like normal as follows.
So I have tried:
Conda install fuzzywuzzy
but it outputs
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: osx-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package fuzzywuzzy-0.18.0-py310hecd8cb5_0 requires python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ fuzzywuzzy is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ fuzzywuzzy 0.18.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ fuzzywuzzy 0.18.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ fuzzywuzzy 0.18.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ fuzzywuzzy 0.18.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ fuzzywuzzy 0.18.0 would require
│     └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

I'm somewhat at a loss. I'm using Python 3.12.4 as of right now. Any ideas about how I can get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Are you working under a virtual env? You may try to create a env withconda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda,activate with
source activate yourenvname
and install fuzzywuzzy
conda install -n yourenvname fuzzywuzzy

As noted on GitHub and in the tag description above, fuzzywuzzy has been renamed to thefuzz.
That explains why

package fuzzywuzzy [..] requires python [...] <3.11.0a0


Oh yes I hadn't noticed! Much appreciated, thank you!

conda install --channel=conda-forge fuzzywuzzy

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
